# How will ConcurrentHashMap with concurrency level 4 and default size 16 work?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

How will ConcurrentHashMap with concurrency level 4 and default size 16 work?

Comment: Which Java version? In all versions which did not reach their “End of Life” yet, the “concurrency level” has no meaning anymore.

Comment: @Holger for Java version 8

Comment: Well, in Java 8, the concurrency level is mostly irrelevant. As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) says: “*Also, **for compatibility with previous versions** of this class, constructors may optionally specify an expected `concurrencyLevel` as an additional hint for internal sizing.*” For an initial capacity of 16 and a concurrency level of 4, the concurrency level has no effect at all.